# Model Mapper give error Failed to convert java.lang.String to java.math.BigDecimal Both destination and Source are string

Tags: java, spring, modelmapper

**I am using `modelmapper.map`  function on these two classes**

=======================Destination======================

```
public class FcTransactionsDto extends BaseDto {
    ........
    private String custIdNumber;
    private String customerType;
    private BigDecimal referenceTransId;
    private String referenceTransactionNumber;
    .....

    public String getCustIdNumber() {
        return custIdNumber;
    }
    public void setCustIdNumber(String custIdNumber) {
        this.custIdNumber = custIdNumber;
    }
}
```

=======================Source==========================

```
public class RemFcTransaction implements java.io.Serializable {

    .................
    private String customerName;
    private String custIdNumber;
    private Boolean specialRateFlag;
    private Boolean kycLimitExceededFlag;


    @Column(name = "CUST_ID_NUMBER", length = 90)
    public String getCustIdNumber() {
        return this.custIdNumber;
    }

    public void setCustIdNumber(String custIdNumber) {
        this.custIdNumber = custIdNumber;
    }
}
```

When the value of `CUST_ID_NO` have value other then numeric  we get 
 following error on  `getCustIdNumber()` function  both source and destination are string

```
org.modelmapper.internal.converter.NumberConverter@502998d8 failed to convert java.lang.String to java.math.BigDecimal
```

Comment: I think issue is with referenceTransId . Check the mapping between 2 object

Comment: i have removed the referenceTransId , still, there is the issue  the error indicates the value which is store in  custIdNumber